# N64 on HDTV white out on snow levels

Tags: nintendo-64

I have my N64 connected to my Samsung Flat screen TV and I'm getting sound and audio, however on snow levels, the whole screen just whites out and (on Mario Kart) I can't see the track.

I'm currently connecting it using the White / Red / Yellow connectors via a SCART cable (as I have a Wii connected to the composite inputs) but do also have a coaxial output on the N64 available (although no coax cable to connect! :D)

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: How do you have it connected? SCART?

Comment: @TZHX updated the initial question

Comment: The best is to download the game via the Virtual Console service provided by the Wii or Wii U.

Comment: @devid That would cost additional funds which I'm less keen on spending as I have the games already.

Comment: @franglais yes I understand that, but the Virtual Console games are optimized to play well on High Definition TV's. If you want to experience these old consoles than you will also need those old TV's. Else you will see pixels and the colors will look awful.

Comment: @franglais Have you fixed this problem, yet?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if it helps at all but I connect mine via the 3 Pin Colored cables into a scart plug, then from that into a HDMI converter box and it works perfectly, I used to have this problem with the snow levels on Mario 64, Never had the problems since.